# Kivy: How to control a realtime graph with an action bar

Tags: python, graph, kivy

I have a graph that updates and add points in realtime, but I want to be able to control it through an ActionBar(i.e play, pause, stop,etc.). So far, no matter what I try, it has not worked. Do I need to convert the graph into some kind of animation?

Below is my .py file

```python
    class Generator(object):
        def __init__(self, period):
            self.period = period
            self.i = 0
        def __call__(self):
            result = self.i%self.period + sin(self.i)+1
            self.i += 1

            return result

    class GraphView(BoxLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(GraphView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            graph_theme = {'label_options': {'color': rgb('444444'),
                                             'bold': True},
                           'background_color': rgb('f8f8f2'),
                           'tick_color': rgb('808080'),
                           'border_color': rgb('808080')}
            self.graph = Graph(xlabel='Times',
                               ylabel='Sales',
                               x_ticks_minor=5,
                               x_ticks_major=10,
                               y_ticks_minor=5,
                               y_ticks_major=10,
                               y_grid_label=True,
                               x_grid_label=True,
                               padding=5,
                               xlog=False,
                               ylog=False,
                               x_grid=True,
                               y_grid=True,
                               **graph_theme)
            self.input_plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[0, 1, 0, 1])
            self.prediction_plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
            self.input_plotpoints = deque(maxlen=100)
            self.predictions_plotpoints = deque(maxlen=100)
            self.graph.add_plot(self.input_plot)
            self.graph.add_plot(self.prediction_plot)
            for i in xrange(10):

                self.wave1 = Generator(24)

                self.wave2 = Generator(13)
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_points, 1 / 100)
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_graph, 1 / 100)

                Clock.schedule_interval(lambda *args: self.add_points(self.wave1(), self.wave2()), 0.2)
            self.add_widget(self.graph)

        def update_points(self, *args):
            self.input_plot.points = zip(range(len(self.input_plotpoints)), self.input_plotpoints)
            self.prediction_plot.points = zip(range(len(self.predictions_plotpoints)), self.predictions_plotpoints)

        def update_graph(self, *args):
            if len(self.input_plotpoints) >3:
                self.graph.ymin= math.ceil(min(self.input_plotpoints))
                self.graph.ymax= math.ceil(max(self.input_plotpoints))

        def add_points(self,active,predictive):
            self.input_plotpoints.append(active)
            self.predictions_plotpoints.append(predictive)
        def pause():
            time.sleep(5)      
class ActionView(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

Below is the .kv file:

```python
<ActionView>:

    use_separator: True
    ActionPrevious:
        title: 'Action Bar'
        with_previous: False
    ActionOverflow:
    ActionButton:
        text: 'Btn0'
        icon: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'
    ActionButton:
        text: 'Start'
    ActionButton:
        text: 'Pause'
        on_release:root.GraphView.pause
    ActionButton:
        text: 'Resume'
    ActionButton:
        text: 'Stop'
    ActionGroup:
        text: 'Group1'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Btn5'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Btn6'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Btn7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was easier than expected. All that was needed was a boolean value (i.e pause=False) and a few if conditions inside the update points and add points functions checking if pause is True.

Create a seperate function that changes pause from its default false to True, and call that function from the action bar (in the .kv)